# How can I push to an array inside of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object created as follow:

```
Obj: {
 error:{
  count: 0,
  id :[]
 }
}
```

I am trying to ad to the list of ids and be able to iterate through the variables in the list of ids, how can you achieve these two goals.

I tried adding using `Obj[error].id.push(["123"])`, but I can't push more than once.
and to view it I tried `Obj[error].id` and `Obj[error].id[0]`, but it returns the count of the items available in the list instead of the value

I am trying to add values so that it can be

```
Obj: {
 error:{
  count: 0,
  id :["123","335"]
 }
}
```

So I would be able to see the values in id and able to add more as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const obj = {
    Obj: {
    error:{
      count: 0,
      id :[]
    }
  }
}

const arr = obj.Obj.error.id;
arr.push('123')
arr.push('1234')

for (const i of arr) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way how you can push multiple values into your array:

```js
const da={Obj:{error:{count:0,id:[]}}};

da.Obj.error.id.push(5,2,4,6);

console.log(da);
// and the array alone:
console.log(da.Obj.error.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work:

```
obj[error].id.push(["123"])
```

Because `error` is undefined. You need to either use dot `.` notation or put quotes around `error`.

```js
const obj = {
    error: {
        count: 0,
        id: [],
    },
};

// With bracket notation
obj['error'].id.push('123', 'abc');

// With dot notation
obj.error.id.push('321', 'cba');

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = {
    Obj: {
    error:{
      count: 0,
      id :[]
    }
  }
}
```

**Adding new elements to the `id` array**

(1) `test.Obj["error"].id.push("123")`

> Notice the quotes around `error`. 
> As `test.Obj[error]` is undefined, hence you have to use quotes around `error`.

(2) `test.Obj.error.id.push("123")`

**Traversing the `id` array** (using the `for` loop)

```js
const arr = test.Obj.error.id;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```